# Safe way to update a label from inside a block?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uikit, objective-c-blocks

Example: I have this block, and I want to update a label on the screen:

```
[self.motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] withHandler:^(CMDeviceMotion *deviceMotion, NSError *error) {
        CMAcceleration *userAcceleration = deviceMotion.userAcceleration;
        self.labelX.text = [NSNumber numberWithFormat:@"%f", userAcceleration.x];
     }];
```

I fear this won't work well. Threading-problems, etc? Suggestions?

Comment: Just an observation: It should be `[NSString stringWithFormat:` since the `text` property is an `NSString`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have reference to the label you can use [performselectoronmainthread](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html) method to update it on the main thread. Yes the UI is not thread safe.

Comment: Someone just pointed out to me that UIKit has been made thread-safe since iOS 4. Is this true?

Comment: The calls are thread safe - that's cool. But for complicated drawing, from multiple (main + nsop) threads at once you may not crash, but end up with a mess from the user's point of view, one would think. It may be for this question that its ok. Also the thread safe thing is only in certain conditions, as laid out in http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniPhoneOS/Articles/iPhoneOS4.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009559-SW29

Answer (score 4):

As a more elegant solution than using `-performSelectorOnMainThread:`, you could simply use a block to guarantee your UI update is on the main thread:

```
[self.motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] withHandler:^(CMDeviceMotion *deviceMotion, NSError *error) {
    CMAcceleration *userAcceleration = deviceMotion.userAcceleration;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.labelX.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", userAcceleration.x];
    });
}];
```

Note that `[NSOperationQueue currentQueue]` will return the main queue if that's where you run the above code from, so your callback will already be running on the main queue in that case.